# Rxjs issue with the concat operator when executing operations sequentially

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I am using rxjs 6 and I am executing two async operations where the order is important.

I do have this chunk of code which works perfectly:

```
dbmsProxy.createDatastores().subscribe(() => {
    UsersDAO.insert(users).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('FINISHED ALL THE CHAIN');
    });
});
```

But when I try to use `concat` of `rxjs` I do have an issue because the second one is executed before the first one finishes:

```
concat([dbmsProxy.createDatastores(), UsersDAO.insert(users)]).subscribe();
```

Below the DBMSProxy methods

```
public createDatastores(): Observable<string> {
    const _this: DBMSProxy = this;
    const subject = new Subject<string>();
    const subscription: Subscription = UsersDAO.createDatastore().subscribe(
        onSuccess,
        onError,
        onFinally
    );
    return subject;

    function onSuccess(datastore: Nedb): void {
        console.log(`USERS Datastore Created Successfully`);
        _this.db.users = datastore;
        subject.next('success');
    }

    function onError(err: string) {
        subject.error('error');
        console.error(err);
    }

    function onFinally() {
        subject.complete();
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}

public insertDocuments(documents: any, datastore: Nedb): Subject<any> {
    const subject = new Subject<any>();
    datastore.insert(documents, onInsert);
    return subject;

    function onInsert(err: Error, newDocuments: any) {
        if (err) {
            subject.error(err);
        } else {
            // add to the documents to insert the id just created from nedb when inserting the document
            documents.forEach((document: any, ind: number) => {
                document.id = newDocuments[ind]._id;
            });
            subject.next(documents);
        }
        subject.complete();
    }
}
```

And below the UsersDAO methods:

```
public static createDatastore(): Subject<Nedb | string> {
        const subject = new Subject<Nedb | string>();
        const datastore = new Nedb({
            filename: USERS_DATASTORE_FULL_NAME,
            autoload: true,
            onload
        });
        return subject;

        function onload(err: Error) {
            if (err) {
                subject.error(
                    `Error creating USERS datastore: ${err.name} - ${err.message}`
                );
            } else {
                subject.next(datastore);
            }
            subject.complete();
        }
    }

    public static insert(users: User[]): Observable<any> {
        return DBMSProxy.getInstance()
            .insertDocuments(users, DBMSProxy.getInstance().db.users)
            .pipe(catchError((val: any) => of('Error inserting the users')));
    }
```

Any idea of what's going on please?

Comment: What is the content of `DBMSProxy.getInstance()`?

Comment: @Dmitri it's the singleton design pattern, it just returns a static instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My current solution is to convert the `Subject` to `Observable`, create a new Observable with the second one, and remove the square brackets (otherwise I will get back the observables and not the results) and this seems to work:

```
const operations = concat(
    dbmsProxy.createDatastores().asObservable(),
    defer(() => UsersDAO.insert(users))
);
operations.subscribe(onSubscribe);
function onSubscribe(result: any) {
    console.log('Finished all: ', result);
}
```

Comment: Use [`defer`](http://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/defer) instead of `new Observable`, etc.

Comment: @cartant I know that's an odd question, but may I ask you why the solution above works? specially why I do need a new observable?

Comment: Your solution is the same as using `defer` - just more verbose. The problem is due to the function being called to evaluate the arg passed to `concat`. With `defer`, the function is called at the time of subscription - which is what you want.

Comment: nope sorry I mean, why I can't just say `const operations = concat(
    dbmsProxy.createDatastores().asObservable(),
    UsersDAO.insert(users)
);` considering that `UsersDAO.insert(users)` already returns an `Observable`?

Comment: ok thanks now it makes sense, sorry I just read the edit. So if I don't use `defer` (or the previous solution), even if using `concat`, the function is anyway executed concurrently with the previous one?

Comment: thanks @cartant I got it, it makes totally sense now. 
The second arg of `concat`, before to encounter the `observable`, executes already the code which expects the first one to be completed.
I thought that `concat` by default executes the code sequentially, but it first gets the observables to chain. Thanks a million!

Comment: the problem is that your 2 functions (createDatastores() and UsersDAO.insert) both return _hot_ observables that have already started their work before you subscribe to them.  When you have observable factories that return hot observables, `defer` is the easiest way to "convert" them into cold observable factories that only do their work when you actually subscribe.  Technically you should also wrap `createDatastores()` in `defer` but in your particular use case (where you synchronously subscribe) it doesn't make a practical difference.